# What laptop should I buy? (Web Developer, Linux)

Tags: laptop, linux

I am a developer, I mostly develop web applications (full stack JavaScript) and websites (mainly WordPress). I use tools like Git, Vagrant (and other kinds of virtualizations), Photoshop, and have a browser open with lots of tabs. Most often lightweight IDEs like Atom, but it happens that I use more heavy IDEs like Webstorm.

I am now looking after a new laptop to buy. I don't want a MacBook and I have been thinking about some of the Laptops from Lenovo's Yoga (2016) Series. But I am not entirely sure about this, mainly because I will dual-boot Windows with Ubuntu (Linux) and I will probably spend more time in Ubuntu then Windows. So a computer that has touch screen does not feel that optimal.

So I would like some recommendations/advice on laptops that are good for my purpose. I am looking for something around the 800-1400 USD price range with SSD and good amount of RAM and a 14" screen. But most importantly I want something that "just works"; in other words, I want a laptop that I can be happy with and that does not come with 102 different bugs and issues.

Answer (score 1):

I currently own a Dell XPS 13 (Developer edition) 16GB RAM, 256 GB SSD. I ran Windows 10 on it for a year, switched to Ubuntu 18.04 for 4 months, and switched back to Windows 10.

Pros:

- It is very lightweight and low-profile
- It can do common tasks with ease such as browsing, word-processing, etc. I normally have around 40-50 tabs open in Google Chrome.

Cons:

- Because it is such a small profile, the case is the cooling system. When running CPU-intensive programs, I can burn my legs from the heat of the aluminum case.
- In Ubuntu, I could not work on the laptop while it was charging because Ubuntu thought the laptop was overheating and the CPU would throttle.

If I could go back and buy another laptop, I would look for something slightly bigger with a better cooling system. Also, the Dell XPS 13 has a CPU that is intended for mobile products. Even though it says Intel core i7, it's not your normal core i7. Lookup i7-8550u for specs. Here is a current link : https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/processors/core/i7-processors/i7-8550u.html

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked, Photoshop is not available on Linux, but I am assuming you're planning to use it on your Windows OS. I would recommend the following, based on my experience:

1. [System76 laptops](https://system76.com/laptops) pre-configured ***OR*** design-your-own (e.g. Serval WS, Oryx Pro, Galago Pro...)
2. [Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-laptops-and-notebooks/xps-13-laptop/spd/xps-13-9370-laptop?view=configurations)
3. [ASUS ZenBook 13 Ultra-Slim Laptop](http://a.co/1sMbavM)
4. [Dell Precision 5520](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/laptops-notebooks/precision-15-5520-laptop/spd/precision-15-5520-laptop?~ck=bt)
5. [HP ZBook 15u G3 Mobile Workstation](https://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-zbook-15u-g2-mobile-workstation-%28energy-star%29-p-v1h63ut-aba--1)

For more choices:

1. [The latest official list of Ubuntu compatible laptops](https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/models/?query=&category=Laptop&level=Enabled&release=16.04%20LTS&vendors=Dell&vendors=Lenovo&vendors=HP&vendors=Intel&vendors=Acer&vendors=Crambo)
2. [Ubuntu laptops on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Ubuntu-Laptops/s?page=1&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3AUbuntu%20Laptops)

Related question:
https://askubuntu.com/q/919794/490067

Source:

I am a Full Stack developer (*.NET, Java &, Python*), Photographer, Microsoft Certified Professional, a decade-long Linux user and a decade-long WordPress blogger. I have used all the technologies you have listed. I am using Lenovo V570 for last 7 yrs, which I have upgraded on my own. Plus, I've [built](https://pcpartpicker.com/b/zvq48d) me a desktop recently.