# Buying a Windows laptop, then install Linux on it?

Tags: laptop, linux, development

I'm looking for a new laptop, mainly for fullstack software development. What (I think) I need:

- Linux (Debian-based, probably Ubuntu or a fork)
- Core i7+
- 16GB+
- SSD 256GB+
- 14"/15"

What I don't really care about:

- Nice-looking laptop
- Powerful graphic card

I don't have a limited budget, but of course looking for the best value for money. I just want to be comfortable with having multiple DBMS/IDE/browsers/processes running at the same time.

I can find some nice laptops with Linux preinstalled (e.g. by Dell or System76), but they are usually quite expensive ($1,000+). On the other hands, some cheaper laptops seem to fulfill these constraints, but have Windows installed by default. I am concerned about driver issues if I buy a Windows laptop, so laptops running Windows must run Linux without issue. Plus, I already have a Windows laptop, so I won't need a dual-boot on the new one.

Comment: I have edited your question to remove the off-topic questions while keeping your concerns. Please edit your question if I missed anything.

Comment: I have installed Linux on several of my windows default laptops, and they work perfectly. For some laptops with fancier features such as RGB, there maybe no Linux drivers, but other then that you should be fine. I personally think you could use a dell latitude which I have installed Linux on in the past(kubuntu)

Comment: Reminder - answers must recommend specific hardware.

Comment: You've contradictory requirements when you say "I don't have a limited budget" and "quite expensive ($1,000+)". Just say your budget is $1000!

Comment: @abalze Good point, I just wanted to mean that I don't want my money to be spent on a nice looking laptop with a powerful graphic card as I know these could be quite expensive, and I simply don't care ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the following, almost all of these come with Ubuntu/Debian/fork installed by manufacturer :

1. [System76 Galago Pro](https://system76.com/laptops/galago)
2. [Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-laptops-and-notebooks/xps-13-laptop/spd/xps-13-9370-laptop?view=configurations)
3. [Dell Precision 5520](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/laptops-notebooks/precision-15-5520-laptop/spd/precision-15-5520-laptop?~ck=bt)
4. [HP ZBook 15u G3 Mobile Workstation](https://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-zbook-15u-g2-mobile-workstation-%28energy-star%29-p-v1h63ut-aba--1) - listed on [Ubuntu website](https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/models/?query=&category=Laptop&level=Enabled&release=16.04%20LTS&vendors=Dell&vendors=Lenovo&vendors=HP&vendors=Intel&vendors=Acer&vendors=Crambo)

For more choices, I recommend looking at [the latest official list of Ubuntu compatible laptops](https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/models/?query=&category=Laptop&level=Enabled&release=16.04%20LTS&vendors=Dell&vendors=Lenovo&vendors=HP&vendors=Intel&vendors=Acer&vendors=Crambo)

Related questions:

1. https://askubuntu.com/q/919794/490067
2. [What laptop should I buy? (Web Developer, Linux)](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2738/9394)